# Type equality constraints and polymorphism

Tags: haskell, polymorphism

What are the exact semantics of equality constraints? Are these two types exactly equivalent?

```
f :: Int -> IO [T]
g :: (a ~ T) => Int -> IO [a]
```

Is `g` a monomorphic or a polymorphic function that happens to only work for T? It trivially seems monomorphic but will the compiler handle it like `f`? The GHC user guide [section on equality constraints](https://downloads.haskell.org/ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#equality-constraints) does not discuss implementation details.

I seem to recall polymorphic functions may require INLINEABLE or SPECIALIZE pragmas to enable all optimizations and there can be a runtime cost to making things needlessly polymorphic. Could that be the case for `g` here as well or will GHC know better and simplify this right away? Or maybe, it depends?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, the types certainly aren't exactly equivalent.

The type-checker considers them different types.  If you compile with `-ddump-types`, you'll see:

```
TYPE SIGNATURES
  f :: Int -> IO [Double]
  g :: forall a. (a ~ Double) => Int -> IO [a]
```

The two types also behave differently at compile time.  For example, with the `TypeApplications` extension, `g @Double 10` is a valid expression while `f @Double 10` isn't.

In core, the equality constraint is implemented -- like all constraints -- as an extra dictionary argument, and you'll see this difference in the types reflected in the generated core.  In particular, if you compile the following program:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}

module EqualityConstraints where

import Control.Monad

f :: Int -> IO [Double]
f n = replicateM n readLn

g :: (a ~ Double) => Int -> IO [a]
g n = replicateM n readLn
```

with:

```
ghc -ddump-types -ddump-simpl -dsuppress-all -dsuppress-uniques \
    -fforce-recomp EqualityConstraints.hs
```

you'll see core like the following:

```
-- RHS size: {terms: 12, types: 22, coercions: 3, joins: 0/0}
g = \ @ a $d~ eta ->
      case eq_sel $d~ of co { __DEFAULT ->
      replicateM
        $fApplicativeIO eta (readLn ($fReadDouble `cast` <Co:3>))
      }

-- RHS size: {terms: 6, types: 4, coercions: 0, joins: 0/0}
f = \ n -> replicateM $fApplicativeIO n (readLn $fReadDouble)
```

and this difference will persist in the core even with `-O2`.

Indeed, if you prevent inlining, the resulting final core (and even the final STG) will involve some unnecessary dictionary passing, as you can see by playing with:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}

import Control.Monad

f :: Int -> IO [Double]
{-# NOINLINE f #-}
f n = replicateM n readLn

g :: (a ~ Double) => Int -> IO [a]
{-# NOINLINE g #-}
g n = replicateM n readLn

main = do
  f 2
  g 2
```

and compiling with `-ddump-simpl` and `-ddump-stg`.

As far as I can see, this difference is still visible even in the optimized assembly with `-O2`.

So, I think it's safe to say that `g` is treated sufficiently polymorphically that the caveats about runtime costs of needless polymorphism do indeed apply.

Comment: Very interesting, thank you! I was somewhat hoping it would be the same :) Now I wonder if there's some low hanging optimization paths not taken by GHC.

Comment: Wow! I was under the impression that coercions were completely absent from the compiled version (since, after all, they don't actually do anything anywhere but in the typechecker that's also completely absent... right?).

Comment: @DanielWagner Casting and coersions seem to be part of [Core](https://www.stephendiehl.com/posts/ghc_03.html) so they should be there all the way until conversion to STG. And indeed I don't see them in the output of `-ddump-stg`.

Answer (score 1):

One big difference is when you use such constraints in a type class.

```
class F a where f :: Int -> IO [a]
instance F Int where f n = pure [1,2,3]
instance (a ~ Int) => F a where f n = pure [1,2,3]
```

If you use the second instance declaration you won't be able to create any other instances because, despite the constraint, all types will unify with a.

Comment: Yeah, this is one of those rite of passage things in Haskell. Almost everyone gets bitten by this. Multiple times even, speaking from my own experience :) It's too tempting to read the constraint as a necessary prerequisite for considering the instance, which is not how instance resolution works.

Comment: This ends up being a very useful trick in certain situations to control type inference. The first instance can only be chosen when the compiler is already certain that the type parameter is `Int` (if it's not certain, it'll give up with an error about an ambiguous type variable). The second instance can be used when the compiler isn't certain about that yet, and then cause it to *become* certain (exactly because there couldn't possibly be any other instances), and use that information to resolve types elsewhere.

Comment: https://chrisdone.com/posts/haskell-constraint-trick/